# Model.findOneAndRemove (MongoDB & Mongoose) specificity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I've been trying to build my first solo CRUD app (without following a tutorial) and came across something a little weird which I can't wrap my head around. Apologies if it's rather obvious, but I couldn't find anything on here about it.

I added my delete route for one of my models and used the following code:

```
// delete list
router.delete("/lists/:id", function(req, res){
    // find list by ID and remove it
    List.findOneAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, deletedList){
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR DELETING LIST");
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/lists");
        } else {
            // if list is removed successfully, remove each item
            console.log(deletedList);
            Item.remove({_id: {$in: deletedList.items}}, function(err, deletedItems){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("ERROR DELETING ITEMS");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LIST & ALL ITEMS");
                    res.redirect("/lists");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now, it deletes things from the database, however it doesn't delete the right thing. I have a button on my web page which submits a form. The form's action is generated based on the page content where I insert the ID of the model into the action using EJS. When I submit the form to delete the model and it's referenced items, it ends up deleting the first document in the database, even though (to my understanding), I've specified that only documents which match the provided ID should be deleted.

I did fix it, by replacing

```
List.findOneAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, deletedList){
            if(err) {
                console.log("ERROR DELETING LIST");
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect("/lists");
            } else {
```

with

```
List.findOneAndRemove({_id: {$in: req.params.id}}, function(err, deletedList){
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR DELETING LIST");
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/lists");
        } else {
```

though I'm not completely sure on why this works and req.params.id doesn't. I was just hoping for some clarification in case I come across something similar in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible reason I can point. When you pass req.params.id to ***findOneAndRemove***, since JS is not a strongly typed language and you are not specifically typing it, Mongoose isn't sure about what to delete.

The first parameter to ***findOneAndRemove*** is the filter object and Mongoose is not able to find the right filtering since the data type that is passed here is a string.

I think then Mongoose consider an empty filter and as usual, empty filter deletes the first item.
One try you can do is to explicitly type the _id, say like

```
var id = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)
```

and pass this id to the findOneAndRemove() function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks. It kind of answered itself when I did a little more testing, but this is pretty much the same conclusion I came to after reading around a little more. I probably should have done a little more research I guess. At least I know for next time!

Comment: I am glad that it helped. If your issue is solved, Please mark this answer approved so that it will help other people coming from the same background.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is deleting the first item in your array because you are using "FindOneAndRemove" - as is suggested in the name, this will limit the match to a single document. And in your first version of the code:

```
List.findOneAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err, deletedList){
```

You aren't specifying your _id field, so i believe it is matching everything, and is only removing a single document due to the method you are using. Where as in the second one, you are

```
List.findOneAndRemove({_id: {$in: req.params.id}}, function(err, deletedList){
```